# Configuring a redirect with a non-existent url for a nested route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the routers set up. They are all wrapped in a parent root with a component that contains an Outlet component (`<ComponentWithOutlet />`). Among the child routes there is another sub-route with its own child routes (`<Route path="foo" />`). All routers work correctly.

```
const RootRouter: FC = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename="/">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<ComponentWithOutlet />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<SomeComponent />} />
          <Route path="foo">
            <Route path="bar" element={<BarComponent />} />
            <Route path="test" element={<TestComponent />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={<Navigate to="/" />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default RootRouter;
```

I want to set up the correct redirect on the wrong url. Now when I navigate to missing urls (for example, `/sdfsdf` or `/foo/asdfsadf`) - the application correctly redirects to the main page. But when I go to the `/foo` url, the `<ComponentWithOutlet />` is rendered, which is wrong. I need to set up a redirect to `/foo/bar` or to the application root.

I tried adding this route to the `<Route path="foo" />`, but it didn't work:

```
<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
```

I tried changing `<Route path="foo" />`, but that didn't work either:

```
<Route path="foo" element={<Navigate to="/" />}>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The code appears to work as I'd expect here in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/configuring-a-redirect-with-a-non-existent-url-for-a-nested-route-jjtevm?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: @DrewReese For the `/foo` url I need a redirect to the page `/foo/bar` or the root of the site. That's not happening right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an unmatched `"/foo/*"` path to redirect to `"/foo/bar"` you'll need to render another redirect for the nested routes. If you want `"/foo"` to also render the `BarComponent` then you'll want an index route that either renders `BarComponent` or redirects to `"/foo/bar"`.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<ComponentWithOutlet />}>
    <Route path="/" element={<SomeComponent />} />
    <Route path="foo">
      <Route path="bar" element={<BarComponent />} />
      <Route path="test" element={<TestComponent />} />
      <Route index element={<Navigate to="bar" replace />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="bar" replace />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit configuring-a-redirect-with-a-non-existent-url-for-a-nested-route]

Comment: After adding `<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="bar" replace />} />` I only get a render of `<ComponentWithOutlet />` and no redirection or changes to the url

Comment: @Jack That should redirect to `"/foo/bar"` and render `BarComponent` like in the linked sandbox.